# Static web application in docker using nginx - localhost refused to connect

Tags: docker, nginx, web, web-deployment, vs-web-application-project

[image]Docker file contains the following command

```
FROM nginx
COPY . /usr/share/nginx/html
```

To build my docker image i have used following command

```
docker build -t <tagName>/img .
```

To run the docker image

```
docker run -p 80:8080 <tagName>/img
```

But i am not able to lanch my static site in my browser . i am getting

```
This site can’t be reached
localhost refused to connect.
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You are mapping port 80 to 8080 here: `docker run -p 80:8080 <tagName>/img`, so to access your app just use the address: 'localhost:80' (or you can ommit the port since 80 is the default port used in browsers)

Answer (score 1):

While Kimi Marie is totally correct, the nginx Dockerfile provides port 80 inside the container. So I assume you would like to map the container's port 80 to your local port 8080. You just need to flip the params like

```
docker run -p 8080:80 <tagName>/img
```

Comment: do you have any idea about this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65124243/static-web-application-in-docker-using-nginx-deployed-in-aws-ec2]