# Static web application in docker using nginx - Deployed in AWS EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, web-development-server, docker-image

I have used to create a docker image with my static web page and nginx server, it works as excepted in my local docker. pushed that image in my docker hub.

have Created EC2 Instance in AWS with the security group as SSH, http and https,
Trying to pull that docker image in EC2 with the following command

```
sudo docker run -p 8080:80 <docker_repo_name>/<tag_name>
```

I am getting the following log (the same log only I am getting my local docker)

```
/docker-entrypoint.sh: /docker-entrypoint.d/ is not empty, will attempt to perform configuration
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Looking for shell scripts in /docker-entrypoint.d/
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh
10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh: Getting the checksum of /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh: Enabled listen on IPv6 in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/20-envsubst-on-templates.sh
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Configuration complete; ready for start up
```

I tried with `http://<public_IP>:8080` But my web page is not loading

Docker file

```
FROM nginx
COPY . /usr/share/nginx/html
```

Comment: can you paste your dockerfile as well.

Comment: @Rezwan `FROM nginx
COPY . /usr/share/nginx/html`